# How can I prove that $f(x)=\det (A+xB)= \alpha x+\beta $?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have two matrices $A$ and $B$, such that :
$$A=A(a,b,c)=\begin{pmatrix} a & c & c & \dots & c \\ b & a & c & \dots & c\\ b & b & a & \dots & c\\ \vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\ b & b & b &\dots& a \end{pmatrix} \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} B=A(1, 1, 1)$$
And we've :
$$f(x)=\det(A+xB)$$
I have to prove the existence of two real numbers  $\alpha$ and $\beta$, such that :
$$f(x)=\alpha x +\beta$$
Just prove their existence not their values, because later in the same exercise we have to calculate $f(-c)$ and $f(-b)$, then deduce their values, then deduce $\det(A)$.

So That's why I think calculating the determinant won't be a good idea I guess. Any Ideas to do so ?

Comment: Hint: use multilinearity of determinants. You can expand out the determinant of $A+xB$ as a sum over whether you choose a particular column of $A$ or $xB$. If you choose two columns of $xB$, then by linear dependence that particular determinant in the expansion is zero.

Comment: Is $A$ a matrix or a matrix-valued function?

Answer (score 5):

In $A+xB$, every entry is of the form $const+x$. We do not change thet determinant if we subtract the first column from every other column. After that, only the first columnt depends on $x$, i.e., the first column is of the form $v+xw$ and all other columns are constant. As $\det$ is linear in every column, the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

This is also true in the more general case where $B$ is rank one matrix and can be expressed as $B=uv^T$ for two vectors $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

When $A$ is invertible, we have that (determinant lemma, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)

$$\det(A+xB)=\det(A+xuv^T)=\det(A)(1+xv^TA^{-1}u)=:\alpha x+\beta,$$

and when $A$ is singular then

$$\det(A+xB)=\det(A+xuv^T)=\det(A)+xv^T\mathrm{Adj}(A)u=:\alpha x+\beta,$$

where $\mathrm{Adj}(A)$ is the adjugate mnatrix of $A$.

Comment: There's a trick you can use here. We are actually dealing with $\det(A(a,b,c)+xB)$, which is a polynomial function in $a$, $b$, $c$, and $x$. When $a$ is large enough in magnitude compared to $b$ and $c$, then by diagonal dominance the matrix $A(a,b,c)$ is invertible, so your first argument holds on an open subset of the parameter space. Since singularity of a matrix is given by a polynomial equation, in fact the argument works on a *dense* subset of the parameter space. The degree of the polynomial in $x$ can't jump up in the complement of a dense subset.

Comment: I like the adjugate argument too, and the adjugate very concretely shows why it works for all matrices without needing to pull in topology and algebraic geometry.